# Create two columns in spark DataFrame with one for cumulative value and another for maximum continuous value

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a spark data frame as below:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql import Window

import pyspark.sql.functions as F

data = [{"Category": 'A', "ID": 1, "Value": 121.44, "Truth": True, "time": 1},
        {"Category": 'B', "ID": 2, "Value": 300.01, "Truth": False, "time": 2},
        {"Category": 'C', "ID": 3, "Value": 10.99, "Truth": None, "time": 3},
        {"Category": 'C', "ID": 4, "Value": 33.87, "Truth": True, "time": 4},
        {"Category": 'D', "ID": 4, "Value": 33.87, "Truth": True, "time": 5},
        {"Category": 'E', "ID": 4, "Value": 33.87, "Truth": True, "time": 6},
        {"Category": 'E', "ID": 4, "Value": 33.87, "Truth": True, "time": 7},
        {"Category": 'E', "ID": 4, "Value": 33.87, "Truth": True, "time": 8}
        ]

spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
df = spark.createDataFrame(data)

w = Window.partitionBy(F.col("Category")).rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, Window.currentRow)
df.filter(df["ID"] == 4).withColumn("val_sum", F.sum(F.col("Value")).over(w)).withColumn("max_time", F.max(F.col("time")).over(w)).show()
```

and I received the follow output:

However, my expected output is like below:

```
+--------+---+-----+-----+----+------------------+--------+
|Category| ID|Truth|Value|time|           val_sum|max_time|
+--------+---+-----+-----+----+------------------+--------+
|       C|  4| true|33.87|   4|             33.87|       4|
|       D|  4| true|33.87|   5|             33.87|       5|
|       E|  4| true|33.87|   6|             33.87|       6|
|       E|  4| true|33.87|   7|             67.74|       7|
|       E|  4| true|33.87|   8|101.60999999999999|       8|
+--------+---+-----+-----+----+------------------+--------+
```

Can anyone please assist me with this?

```
+--------+---+-----+-----+----+------------------+--------+
|Category| ID|Truth|Value|time|           val_sum|max_time|
+--------+---+-----+-----+----+------------------+--------+
|       C|  4| true|33.87|   4|             33.87|       4|
|       D|  4| true|33.87|   5|             33.87|       5|
|       E|  4| true|33.87|   6|             33.87|       8|
|       E|  4| true|33.87|   7|             67.74|       8|
|       E|  4| true|33.87|   8|101.60999999999999|       8|
+--------+---+-----+-----+----+------------------+--------+
```

Please do let me know if it is not clear so that I could provide more info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define another window spec for max function with `unboundedPreceding` and `unboundedFollowing` instead of `currentRow`

**`Example:`**

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql import Window

import pyspark.sql.functions as F

data = [{"Category": 'A', "ID": 1, "Value": 121.44, "Truth": True, "time": 1},
        {"Category": 'B', "ID": 2, "Value": 300.01, "Truth": False, "time": 2},
        {"Category": 'C', "ID": 3, "Value": 10.99, "Truth": None, "time": 3},
        {"Category": 'C', "ID": 4, "Value": 33.87, "Truth": True, "time": 4},
        {"Category": 'D', "ID": 4, "Value": 33.87, "Truth": True, "time": 5},
        {"Category": 'E', "ID": 4, "Value": 33.87, "Truth": True, "time": 6},
        {"Category": 'E', "ID": 4, "Value": 33.87, "Truth": True, "time": 7},
        {"Category": 'E', "ID": 4, "Value": 33.87, "Truth": True, "time": 8}
        ]
spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
df = spark.createDataFrame(data)

w = Window.partitionBy(F.col("Category")).rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, Window.currentRow)
w1 = Window.partitionBy(F.col("Category")).rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, Window.unboundedFollowing)
df.filter(df["ID"] == 4).withColumn("val_sum", F.sum(F.col("Value")).over(w)).withColumn("max_time", F.max(F.col("time")).over(w1)).show()

+--------+---+-----+-----+----+------------------+--------+
|Category| ID|Truth|Value|time|           val_sum|max_time|
+--------+---+-----+-----+----+------------------+--------+
|       E|  4| true|33.87|   6|             33.87|       8|
|       E|  4| true|33.87|   7|             67.74|       8|
|       E|  4| true|33.87|   8|101.60999999999999|       8|
|       D|  4| true|33.87|   5|             33.87|       5|
|       C|  4| true|33.87|   4|             33.87|       4|
+--------+---+-----+-----+----+------------------+--------+
```

Comment: Why not just `w1 = Window.partitionBy("Category")`? It gives the same result.

Comment: Thank you so much. You are right, it seems like I keep using single window and didn't think out of the box to have more than 1. I will accept this as answer after the the time constraint.

Comment: Vlad Siv, can you explain a little more? I am curious.

Comment: @VladSiv, That also works, as Spark default to `unboundedPreceeding and Following`!

Comment: AFAIK, the definition of the Window `w` will produce in random results on real data, if there is no `.orderBy()` statement added, because the ordering for the cumulative sum is not fixed.
The present code only works because of the inline-creation of the test data.